# How to pass callback from TableView to TableView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableview`.In each cell of `tableview`, there is an upload button. On Click of that button, I am using the protocol delegate mechanism to tell the TableViewVC that I need to show the file picker option. What I don't understand is how to pass callback from TableView to TableView Cell when a particular file is selected for a particular cell so that I can change visibility of a label in that cell.

Here is my code when button in a cell is clicked

```
protocol FileUploadDelegate {
    func uploadFile(documentId: Int,position: Int)
}

@IBAction func uploadDocumentClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.uploadFile(documentId: documentId,position: position)
    }
```

In my `TableViewVC` I have implemented the protocol and written all the code for file picker

Now in the following method

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

}
```

I need to pass callback from tableView to the exact tableCell which triggered the action so that I can change visibility of a label in that cell. How can I achieve that?

Comment: When the UIButton is tapped, it will upload the file or show the document picker?

Comment: @wint It will show the document picker

Comment: @Kutta Do you have a data model for the cells?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this method like this:

```
protocol FileUploadDelegate {
    func uploadFile(documentId: Int,position: Int, cellIndexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

you get cell what you need to update later. you can save as property (for example)
after this you can update in method:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

}
```

via `tableView.reloadData()`

and inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can update special cell with indexpath that you saved

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCell.swift

```
class tableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
 var onButtonTapped : (() -> Void)? = nil
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

 }
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let onButtonTapped = self.onButtonTapped {
        onButtonTapped()
    }
}
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource{

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  numberOfItemsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {
     guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
     "youridhere", for: indexPath) as? cellname else 
     { return UICollectionViewCell() }

        cell.onButtonTapped = {
            filepicker.item = . 
 self.model.item[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell

  }
}
```